Unable to offload to GPU using openMP in gcc, omp_get_num_devices returns 0
I've made a simple test program to offload a SAXPY workload to the GPU with openMP, but have been unable to detect the presence of the GPU. I'm unsure if the compiler is configured correctly for this purpose.
omp_get_num_devices() returns 0, indicating there is no available target for offloading. omp_is_initial_device() also returns 1 within the target region, which indicated it is falling back to the CPU. This machine has a 4070ti, an i7-11700 (which has an iGPU), and is running Linux Mint 21.
The command I am using for compilation is the following:
g++ -fopenmp -g -O2 saxpy.cpp -o saxpy

Running gcc -v in order to determine if it is properly configured, I get the following:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)

Looking at --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none, I am inclined to believe it should be able to offload to the NVIDIA GPU on the machine. I am unsure how to proceed, how can I further diagnose the problem, and ultimately get at least one of the GPUs to be recognized and used for offloading?
Lastly, here is the source code. I believe this part isn't the source of the problem, but just in case:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define SAXPY_SIZE 1024*1024*1024

void saxpy(float a, float* x, float* y, int sz) {
    double runtime = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp target device(1) map(to:x[0:sz]) map(tofrom:y[0:sz])
    {
        #pragma omp parallel for simd firstprivate(a)
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        {
            y[i] = a * x[i] + y[i];
        }
        printf("%d\n", omp_is_initial_device());
    }

    runtime = omp_get_wtime() - runtime;
    printf("%8d kb SAXPY Runtime: %lf\n", sz/1024, runtime);
}

int main(void) {
    float a, *x, *y;
    x = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * SAXPY_SIZE);
    y = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * SAXPY_SIZE);

    printf("%d devices\n", omp_get_num_devices());

    for (size_t i = 4096; i <= SAXPY_SIZE; i *= 2)
    {
        saxpy(1.0, x, y, i);
    }
    
    return 0;
}


Assuming linux ... Are you sure the nvidia device driver et. al. is configured correctly? Look at lspci, lsmod, etc. Your GPU is approx one year old. It may be too new for your openmp version? Can you write a small cuda version of your program (without any omp) and check the results of an nvcc generated program to verify that userspace can use the GPU? I assume you've seen: https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/2021-10-20-Webinar-OpenMP-Offload-Programming-Introduction.pdf or similar

I am not sure how to check if it's configured correctly, but lspci lists both GPUs, here is the 4070ti:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2782 (rev a1)
I can't make much sense of lsmod, but the nvidia related entries are the following:
nvidia_uvm           1519616  0 nvidia_drm             94208  3 nvidia_modeset       1327104  3 nvidia_drm nvidia              56172544  34 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
I will try cuda now. Regarding the tutorial, yes, that is very similar to the one I followed.

According to https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Offloading you might need to add -foffload=nvptx-none.

@CraigEstey I have confirmed that a cuda version of the program works correctly. It compiles and runs. @Joachim Thank you, I missed that. That results in a different error, which was similar to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66157459/gcc-fails-to-compile-openmp-offloading-to-gpu . Resolving it through -fcf-protection=none -fno-stack-protector leads to yet another error, unresolved symbol __printf_chk. I suppose it's progress!

Printf in a target region is problematic. You should get the value from the device before calling I/o functions.

@Joachim you're right, I was aware but completely forgot I had a print inside that zone. It compiles, I will do some further testing to ensure everything works right.

Everything seems to work right. omp_is_initial_device is returning 0, and the execution time changed significantly, which indicates it is being offloaded. omp_get_num_devices is also returning 1, naturally. I do get two warnings that I don't know the meaning of, but hopefully they won't cause trouble: /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDJr9Ho.crtoffloadtable.o: warning: relocation against __offload_vars_end in read-only section .rodata /usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
